# Editing slightly broken code and accepting it as answer to your question

Tags: discussion, edits, accepted-answer

So this is in response to this edit I suggested:  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2333287

I may have unjustly made an edit here (voting is split, so even if it is approved it's contentious), but I wanted to make the edit and accept this person's answer since I would not have solved the issue without her or his suggestion. It seemed unfair to answer the question myself, especially since it was probably just an oversight that the person didn't include the second argument in the code submitted (which, that was the egregious error).

Any advice here? Would you add your own answer and accept that, or attempt to edit the original code?

Comment: Comment on the answer first. If the other user doesn't reply or edit the answer after some reasonable time, you may suggest an edit.

Comment: If you were changing the edit substantially...say adding completely new things you discovered after you read the answer, then I would say a comment is the right answer.  In this case, though, it seems like a legitimate edit, as it really was just fixes to the code.

Answer (score 7):

> **Disclaimer:** I'm speaking for myself here. I'm fairly normal, so the thoughts here should apply to many other 2kers.

---

Let me give you some insight on how 2kers reviewing suggested edits think:

The first thing we see when reviewing suggested edits is the 'edit summary'. You know, the really annoying thing that you just want to leave blank. Well, we actually look at that.

If we see the words 'changed code', or any variation or permutation thereof, we have a very specific protocol we follow:

> <kbd>Reject</kbd> > <kbd>Invalid edit</kbd>

You see, we don't check to see if the editor was the OP. All we are about is whether the edit is one that makes nice little grammar and spelling and formatting changes, or makes a huge change - like code.

First, leave a comment to the answerer that says something like:

> Thanks! I just needed to make change `X`, `Y` and `Z` to make it work. Could you edit these into your answer, so that I can accept it?

If the author doesn't comply, or isn't active and you really feel the code needs to be fixed for the answer to be accepted, **here's a tip**: Don't put 'changed code' (or any permutation thereof!) in the edit summary. Put something like:

> I AM THE OP!!! I made some minor changes to the code so that it better fits my question.

Even then, there will be those that simply want to squash your fun. If worst comes to worst, ping a 2ker in chat and ask them to make the fix.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense...sort of a 'best of both worlds' where I still can give the OP credit!